# Why printer leave black marks on paper?

Tags: printer

I have a `HP Laserjet 1018` and recently when i try to print a page with it ,it leaves several black lines in the paper with a spacific distance from each other, when i print a with image or an image with a small amount of black letters it's not happening. what's wrong with it?

here is an image of a printed page:

[image]

**Maybe this question is off-topic in here I'm reading the [what's on topic here article](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) but I'm not quit sure. if so please direct me to the correct forum**

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. This is most likely off-topic, but there's probably not a good StackExchange site for this to actually exist on either. As for your problem, this looks like you have a dirty roller, or excess toner on your fuser. You might be able to clean it off if you take the printer apart, but there's nothing we can really suggest without being able to see inside the printer itself.

Comment: @MichaelFrank tanks for you reply, I'll try opening it and see what's wrong with the roller.

Comment: The distance between the marks is the circumference of the roller that causes them. That makes it easier to find the correct roller. Also, most printers have a "repeating defects" list, which shows, for each roller, the distance between the marks. Check the manual or on-line support database.

Comment: Some printers can be cleaned with a piece of paper sprayed with rubbing alcohol; I find it easiest to spray a single sheet after I put it in the paper holder. Check your printer instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [User Manual](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00585348.pdf) for your printer has a section about printing defects that starts on page 66. It talks about repetitive defects on page 68 (page 76 of the PDF) and lists the following possible causes:

> 1. The print cartridge might be damaged. If a repetitive mark occurs at the same spot on the page, install a new HP print cartridge. See
>      Changing the print cartridge for instructions.
> 2. The internal parts might have toner on them. See Cleaning the printer for more information. If the defects occur on the back of the
>      page, the problem will probably correct itself after a few more
>      printed pages.
> 3. In your printer driver, make sure that the appropriate media type is selected.

Cleaning the printer is listed on pg 42 (pg 50 of the PDF).